# Analytics Reporting API v4 "viewId must be set" issue

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We are using [Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java) in our backend to process analytical data collected from our clients (apps & website). We are facing an issue that the reporting API requires a `viewId` parameter to be present in the request that queries analytical data, otherwise the request fails.

```
// create the ReportRequest object
ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest().setViewId("your-view-id-here")
       .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
       .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser))
       .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));
```

According to their documentation, the `viewId` parameter can be extracted from the Google Analytics Console, which is correct.

The problem we are facing is that our "Website" property in Google Analytics already has a view where we can extract the ID from under it's settings:

[image]

This is great and exactly what we need, but for the "iOS" and "Android" properties, there is no view and the button to create one is **greyed out**:

[image]

Is there any way to query the API without specifying a viewId or is there a way to create a view in the console that we are unaware of?

Could the issue be caused by the fact that we are using Firebase to collect our data in Android and iOS?

Comment: Yes its becouse the view was created with firebase analytics not google analytics.   See if you can dig the view id out of firebase not even sure if thats posible.   I think there is a firebase analytics API though that you can use.

Comment: So there is no way to query this kind of data with "Reporting API" even though it shows up in GA console as well? Could you link me to the corresponding Firebase API? All I have found is an API to send analytical data to Firebase.

Comment: Sorry no idea really was a guess i dont use firebase for analytic would rather use google anlaytics.   But heres an idea.    https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.accountSummaries.list  Authenticate that see if it will return your view id.

Comment: Let me know either way I want to bring this up with the team.  Seams silly if you cant use it.

Comment: You were right, it only works with firebase - I am still unable to query data collected with firebase even tough it shows up in GA console.

Comment: I have the exact same issue here. Any updates?

Comment: What a joke! Unbelievable! After I managed to set everything I'm getting this.

Comment: The funny thing is in the V4 docs's sample php code there is viewid present but V4 doesn't have views so even the docs conflicts with itself :D https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php